# Why my regular expression not correct in my data?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new in regular expression,write this regular expression:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(txtName, @"^[آ-ی]$"))
            {
                int x = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                message += Environment.NewLine + "فیلد نام معتبر نمی باشد";

            }
```

```
txtName value is :ابراهیم
```

but when run up if block,else segment run,why?thanks.

Comment: I assume that your regular expression is looking for alphabetic characters. Is your string, in fact, in the range you specify? (I don't actually read the language in question so it's impossible to know).

Comment: I wouldn't use the '^' (beginning line) and '$' (end line) together especially in languages that are right to left.

Comment: It can be useful to try one of the helpful online parsers that are available these days. This is just the first one that came up with a google search: http://regexstorm.net/tester It can be helpful to see how the expression is working against a variety of input. Or to try to rebuild your expression a bit at a time.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is an invaluble tool when working with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> @"^[آ-ی]$"
> ```

I don't think you want to mach only strings with a single char, so try

```
@"^[آ-ی]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Named Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_12) here for Arabic characters.

Example:

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtName, @"(\p{IsArabic}+(\s)?)+");
```

This will match the pattern of one or more Arabic characters followed by zero or one white-space characters one or more times.  Tested as working with your input string.

Here's a more in depth reference from [MSDN with additional examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock).

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about this! It looks like `\p{IsArabic}` matches [all Arabic characters](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) (i.e., it will match on punctuation and other "non-alphabet" characters), can you give an example of how to combine it with `\p{L}` to only return true for Arabic letters?